# How to update index value of while controller in Thread Group of Jmeter?

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

I am having a thread group containing HTTP request, JDBC request, If and While controller. Whenever I try to run thread group more than 1 time (using loop controller or by specifying number of times execution required in thread group), then HTTP, JDBC request are executed but while controller is not getting executed.
post using Debug sampler found that index of while controller is not getting changed hence it is not getting executed post 1st time.

Comment: What do you have in the `Condition` field of the While Controller? The looping index will be incremented when the condition is passed  (i.e true)

Comment: I have written like this "${__javaScript("${CSPURGEJOB}".indexOf("UBMITTED") == -1,)}"
my expectation is when the status in 'CSPURGEJOB' is SUBMITTED then it should break the while loop and move ahead for next

Comment: Can you try following in the while controller `${__groovy(vars.get("CSPURGEJOB") == "SUBMITTED" )}` ? BTW I can see `S` is missing in the `indexOf("UBMITTED")` part of your expression.

Comment: I have removed 'S' as it will verify position at index -1 once it find value then it will break the loop and move forward.
I tried ${__groovy(vars.get("CSPURGEJOB") == "SUBMITTED" )} but with this it is not going only in while loop

Answer (score 0):

1. While Controller finishes its execution when (if) its "Condition" becomes `false`
2. When you enter 2nd iteration of the Thread Group the "Condition" is still `false` so threads (virtual users) don't enter the While Controller

You need to **reset** the variable(s) used in the While Controller so the "Condition" of the While Controller becomes `true` again somewhere in the end of the 1st iteration, it can be done using either [Set Variables Action](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) sampler or using [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) or whatever is the most convenient way for you to do this.

Comment: tried using set variable, it is not working